# How to convert time to 24Hr format from DateTime.Now

Tags: c#

Here is my code, there is an error regarding the last line stating that

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.TimeSpan'

```
//Getting the current date and time
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
//Date
var date = dateTime.Date;
//Time
var time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
time = time.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: `time` is `TimeSpan` and you are trying to assign it a string

Comment: Assign the return value of `time.ToString("HH:mm")` to a separate variable which has a type of `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the third line of your code you declared variable named time (`var time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;`) by using var.

> [Var.](https://www.dotnetperls.com/var) This keyword references a type in an implicit way. It aliases any type. The aliased type is determined by the C# compiler. This has no performance penalty.

So the data type of variable time is TimeSpan because the `TimeOfDay()` Method returns a `TimeSpan` and then in the next line you tried to assign time a  string value that in a type-safe language such as C# returns an error.
You should simply declare another value:

```
//Getting the current date and time
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
//Date
var date = dateTime.Date;
//Time
var time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
var timeOfDayStr = time.ToString("HH:mm");
```

If you want to get the time in 24Hour format you should do this:

```
var TimeIn24HrFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

For Hour and minute, You can do simply:

```
String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", DateTime.Now)
```

Similarly:
If you want full format:

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your time variable is a Timespan type, but you are trying to assign a string to it. C# is a statically typed language so variables cannot change type during runtime. Simply make a new variable for your time string:

```
var time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
var time24hr = time.ToString("HH:mm");
```