# Format value inside list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model like this:

```
   public class MyViewModel
    {
        public TimeSpan AverageLogOn { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan AverageLogOff { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan AverageTotalHours { get; set; }
        
    }
```

I use this model as a list like:

```
  public IList<MyViewModel> MyViewModelList { get; set; } = new List<MyViewModel>();
```

That I want to do is to format `AverageLogOn` to "hh:mm:ss" how can I do with LINQ, I think something like:

```
 MyViewModel.Select(x => new MyViewModel { AverageLogOn = x.AverageLogOn.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), AverageLogOff = x.AverageLogOff, AverageTotalHours = x.AverageTotalHours });
```

But when I tried `x.AverageLogOn.ToString("hh:mm:ss")` it throw an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.TimeSpan'

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: ToString creates a string and the target type is TimeSpan.  You either need to assign a Timespan, not a string, or you need to change the target type to string.

Comment: Moreover, `TimeSpan` does not _have_ a format - you specify a format when you want to _display_ it. You should specify the format _there_, not in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to assign a `string` to a property that requires a `TimeSpan` value. Just like the error message says. Basically, the same as in this question: [How to convert time to 24Hr format from DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48364289).

You didn't provide much context, so it's not clear how you expect to use the result of your `Select()` call. It is *possible* that it's in a context where a `string` value actually makes sense for those properties. If so, then you can just drop the `MyViewModel` from the code and create an anonymous type instead:

```cs
MyViewModelList.Select(x => new { AverageLogOn = x.AverageLogOn.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), AverageLogOff = x.AverageLogOff, AverageTotalHours = x.AverageTotalHours });
```

You'll get an enumeration of objects, the type of which is unnamed (i.e. "anonymous"), and *different from* your original `MyViewModel` object type, where the `AverageLogOn` property now has type `string` instead of `TimeSpan`. Note however that there are limitations on the ways anonymous types can be used. But, since WPF does everything in XAML without much type safety, it's entirely possible this would do exactly what you want.

**Note:** you don't show in your post how you actually use the result of the call to `Select()`. But I want to make sure you understand that `Select()` does not do anything to the original collection. It's not going to modify `MyViewModelList`. The `Select()` method returns an instance of `IEnumerable<MyViewModel>` here, and you have to use that reference in some way to actually see the work that `Select()` did. (Indeed, until you actually "materialize" that enumeration, i.e. enumerate the sequence of values somehow, nothing actually happens at all, not even the instantiation of the anonymously-typed objects.)

On the other hand, maybe all you really need is to adjust your XAML to format the `TimeSpan` values the way you want. In that case, you don't need the `Select()` method at all. Instead, you'll want to include the `StringFormat` specifier in your binding markup, something like this:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding AverageLogOn, StringFormat={}{0:hh}:{0:mm}}" />
```

See this question for a little more information on that: [How to format converter paramter in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33006979).

The cause of the error itself is obvious, and the error message seems clear enough. Lacking more detail on why you got yourself into that situation in the first place, it's difficult to know for sure what the actual *answer* to your question should be. I think the above should adequately address your concerns, but if these suggestions don't solve your problem, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64702391/edit) to improve it so that it's clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

Try using an extension methods, remember that days can be more than 24

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToCustomString(this TimeSpan span)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
    }
}
```

You'd then call

```
x.AverageLogOn.ToCustomString()
```

you can also call

```
x.AverageLogOn.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Again, you will miss the days

Update thanks David:
I missed the conversion error, you can parse a string using a statement that returns timespan or a "zero" timespan if it fails

TryParse(string,out var time)? time : Timespan.FromSeconds(0)

Have a look at the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_TryParse_System_String_System_TimeSpan__)

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem since the OP will still be assigning a string to a TimeSpan.